# How to stop the looping in adobe animated?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

```
BStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, Menu);

function Menu(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1, Menu);
}
```

I use adobe animated, i make 2 scene. My first scene do have 1 button 'START'. This button i use to go to second scene which is 'MENU'. I have put the code 'Click To Go To Scene And Play' in my button, but then when i test, it keep looping non-stop. I already make new layer to put the stop. Even in every single layer i put it, but it still looping. I have follow many tutorial in youtube, but all end up useless.

Comment: Try using the `Debug` option (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) not `Test Movie` option. Does debugging show any errors?

Comment: I don't remember how it works with actions on the button itself but shouldn't it be "Click to go to Scene and Stop" there ? Play will play the scene. And like VC One said it might also loop if there are any code errors in the Menu scene